# Powershell Object array to Convertto-html

Tags: powershell

New to powershell and need help on formatting as below. Since the variable Object array not having any property to select not sure how to get the key value and convert to html   as table.

```
$localAccounts
Principal   Is Group  Role    Role Description
----------  --------  ------  ---------------------------------------------------------
User1           false  Admin   Full access rights
User2           false  Admin   Full access rights
User3           false  Admin   Full access rights
User4           false  Custom  User-defined roles or roles on non-root inventory objects
User5           false  Custom  User-defined roles or roles on non-root inventory objects

$localAccounts.GetType()                                                                                                                                                                       
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

I need an output as html as table 

UserName    Role    Description
User1       Admin   Full access rights
User2       Admin   Full access rights
User3       Admin   Full access rights
User4       Custom  User-defined roles or roles on non-root inventory objects
User5       Custom  User-defined roles or roles on non-root inventory objects
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"Since the variable Object array not having any property to select"_? I see 4 properties on the objects in the array: `Principal`, `Is Group`, `Role` and `Role Description` ... All you have to do is output that in a HTML table format with [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html).

Comment: Please find the below as not seeing any property other than length 
$localAccounts | gm
   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------                     
$localAccounts[0]
Principal   Is Group  Role    Role Description

Comment: Below might give some idea about it
$localAccounts[0]
Principal   Is Group  Role    Role Description
 $localAccounts[1]
----------  --------  ------  ---------------------------------------------------------
$localAccounts[2]                                                                                                                                                                              User1           false  Admin   Full access rights
$localAccounts[3]
root           false  Admin   Full access rights

Comment: Please put this info as formatted text in your question, not as a comment, because that becomes unreadable (swallows newlines etc.) Also, what does ` $localAccounts | Format-Table -AutoSize` show in the console? What do you get if you do ` $localAccounts | ConvertTo-Html` ? and how did you obtain this array `$localAccounts` in the first place?

Comment: To me, is looks like you *_HAD_* an array of objects with those properties, used `Format-Table` on it and captured that as string array in variable $localAccounts. In that case, keep the object array as is and pipe to [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$localAccounts | select Principal,Role,"Role Description" | ConvertTo-Html`.

But if you want  to change the header names you need to convert the items to PSCustomObjects first.

```
$localAccounts | %{ [PSCustomObject]@{
   UserName=$_.Principal
   Role=$_.Role
   Description=$_.'Role Description'} | ConvertTo-Html
```

Comment: Please find the below as not seeing any property other than length 
$localAccounts | gm
TypeName: System.String            
Below might give some idea about it
$localAccounts[0]
Principal   Is Group  Role    Role Description
 $localAccounts[1]
----------  --------  ------  ---------------------------------------------------------
$localAccounts[2]                                                                                                                                                                              User1           false  Admin   Full access rights

Comment: If all you have is an array of string then what you're trying to do will be quite difficult and prone to errors. If you update your question with how you create your $localAccounts variable, we might be able to help you.